# Why am I getting an empty list instead of [0] when N=1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on list comprehension

```
[0 if N<2 else val*2 for val in range(0,N//2)]
```

when N<2 I expect out put to be [0] but I am getting []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your expression is read from the computer's perspective.

```
[(0 if N < 2 else val * 2) for val in range(0, N // 2)]
```

So the `for` bit happens first. And if `N` is less than `2`, then `range(0, N // 2)` is empty, so the `0 if N < 2 else val * 2` bit never actually executes.

In your case, it would make more sense to simply have two different cases.

```
if N < 2:
  return [0]
else:
  return [val * 2 for val in range(0, N // 2)]
```

Or, if you want it in one line,

```
[0] if N < 2 else [val * 2 for val in range(0, N // 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If `N = 1`, then `N//2 = 0`. So your for loop is not executing, since it would be a range from 0 to 0. You can do `[val * 2 for val in range(0, N // 2)] if N >= 2 else [0]`

Answer (score 0):

1//2 is 0, so you have range(0, 0) which is an empty list, hence the map part of the list comprehension isn't executed at all.

If you want to get [0] for N<2 you probably want to do it like this:

```
[val*2 for val in range(0,N//2)] if N<2 else [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. try the following:

```
N = 3
a = [0 if N<2 else val*2 for val in range(0,N//2)]
#output: [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do list indexing:

```
print([[val * 2 for val in range(0, N // 2)],[0]][N<2])
```

Or `dict.get`:

```
print({0:[val * 2 for val in range(0, N // 2)],1:[0]}.get(N<2))
```

Both reproduce the expected result.